# Smartcard error accessing with curl to a web service

Tags: linux, curl, smartcard

I try to comunicate with a webservice that need a smartcard autenthication.It works is some cases, fails in others, depending on the smartcard.
With smartcard with IDEMIA chip the simple script

```bash
ENDPOINT=https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.it/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
ls -la > test
curl -s -k --trace-ascii xxx.trace \
--cert "pkcs11\:object=$CERT_CARD_NOW}:${PIN_CARD_NOW}" --key  "pkcs11:object=${PRIV_CARD_NOW}" \
-H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate' \
-H "Content-Type: multipart/related; type=\"application/xop+xml\"; start=\"<rootpart@soapui.org>\"; start-info=\"text/xml\"; \
-H 'SOAPAction: "http://============================================="' \
-H 'MIME-Version: 1.0' \
-H 'Host: --------------------------------' \
-H 'Connection: Keep-Alive' \
-H 'User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.5.5 (Java/16.0.1)' \
--data-binary @test  $ENDPOINT*
```

Works,
but with several other smartcards the trace is this (error 58)
(chip NXP STM)

```
== Info:   Trying -----------------...

== Info: Connected to ---------------------------- (-------------)
port 443 (#0)
== Info: ALPN: offers h2
== Info: ALPN: offers http/1.1
== Info: unable to set client certificate
== Info: Closing connection 0
```

With all the cards this simple script works

```bash
echo -n "File to sign:" 
read file
openssl dgst -sha256 -engine pkcs11 -keyform engine \
-sign "pkcs11:${PRIV_CARD_NOW};pin-value=${PIN_CARD_NOW}" $file > 
$file.signed
```

With all the cards the certificate extraction with `p11tool --export-stapled "pkcs11:<<Cert_uri>>` works and all the pcks11-tool `p11tool` work as expected. Someone can tell me if is a curl problem or an openssl problem and how to solve ?

The version indication that `curl -V` shows `7.83.1 OpenSSl/1.1.1q-fips` (etc.).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Never mind the bot, but please have a look to see how MarkDown editing works, and if that's too much, use the buttons correctly. See my [edit] on how to format.

Comment: Yes, I was not able to make correct use of the code button

Comment: Thank you for the reformatting, now is more readable.

Comment: I think maybe it is a problem with smartcards' linux drivers, there is someone that knows  if the windows curl version works better ? And where I would find a curl windows binary with pkcs#11 enabled, I am not able to build it from scratch.